# POWERSHELL - The member's SID could not be resolved

Tags: powershell

Hello im working with Active Directory Group and Users and i wanna check and set  proper Users/Groups from AD to machines. Problem is when i iterate over Local Users/Groups on some machine and there is old Users/Group that no longer exists in AD POWERSHELL will stop working and will throw exception.

> An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved.

I know what causes this problem but i dont know how to work around it. The main issue here is that its not even possible to iterate over whole array of users if one is no longer valid. Only solution to this is manualy delete those invalid users.

I even saw some reports to Microsoft that this behaviour is wrong and should be fixed but nothing was done about it.

Anyone here encountered this issue?

Thank you for your help.

```
$ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
$computer = "PC name"
$groupName = "Administrators"
$context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList   $ctype, $computer
$idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
$groupData = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, $groupName)   
$groupData.Members |  select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}},@{N='Group'; E={$groupName}} , @{N='Account Name/Group'; E={$_.SamAccountName}}
```

Here is example of code that im using for iterating over Local users/groups on some PC.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using directoryservices.accountmanagement instead of using  the standard AD cmdlets like get-aduser, get-adgroupmember etc? You could short down the posted code snippet to 1 or 2 (readable) lines with the native cmdlets

Comment: Well with those commands that you have listed you will get Users specified in AD. My code logs on computer and get users and groups that are set on machine. Its not same thing.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/763667/get-local-group-member-an-error-1332-occurred-while-enumerating-the-group-membership this is the error im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Can You post the code that you are using, and the full error.  Im guessing there is a workaround, but without seeing your code I can't see what could be wrong.  If a terminating error is thrown it will stop the script or function from running further (with some gotchas, and exceptions), there are many ways of working around this

Also could you post the full error.

You will probably need to set the $erroractionpreference to silentlycontinue. And then review the $error variable to check the errors, but again I am only speculating.

Comment: Well the reason why im posting this here is because i tried everything i coudl think of like 4-5 ways of Try,Catching ,, Silentlycontinue ETC. everything the error still goes trough and ruins the script.

Comment: Seems like you were on the right track.  Is it a native PowerShell cmdlet that you are using? Different errors for different types of commands behave differently in powershell.  Look at the The Big Book of PowerShell Error Handling on powershelgl.org.  Unfortunately without seeing code I can't help you.  I understand that you may not be able to post the full code, but even a mocked up version covering the key logic where the error is thrown would be helpful.  Cheers